# MongoDb: Combine two find operations together

Tags: mongodb

When I search for documents containing title 'Apple' as such:

> db.getCollection('items').find({title: {$regex: 'Apple'}})

The documents with title containing 'Apple' are returned as expected

When I search for documents where priceA is less than priceB as such:

> db.getCollection('items').find({"$where":"this.priceA < this.priceB"})

The documents where priceA is less than priceB are returned as expected.

**However**, when I try to do both together as such:

> db.getCollection('items').find({title: {$regex: 'Apple'}},
>   {"$where":"this.priceA < this.priceB"})

Only the _id field is returned, and it's really all the documents in my collection and the two filters above are not applied at all:

[image]

How do I apply both filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is wrong try this. You are passing the second condition wrong in projection method [check this out for more details](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

Mongodb find() method takes 3 arguments

**condition**:`{title: {$regex: 'Apple'},"$where":"this.priceA < this.priceB"}`

**Projection:**

By default t you wont specify any thing in projection it will return you the entire document but if you want only specific details you can pass it like **{name:1,email:1}**

**Options:**
sample example is`{sort:1,limit:1}`

```
  db.getCollection('items').find({title: {$regex: 'Apple'},"$where":"this.priceA < this.priceB"}, {})
```